# Actionscript: size of parent depending on child's width and coordinates

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have the problem with width of parent sprite. I create two sprites: parent and child

```
var parent:Sprite = new Sprite();
var child:Sprite = new Sprite();

addChild(parent);
parent.addChild(child);

child.x = 20;
child.y = 20;
child.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
child.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
trace("colorBox.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);");
trace("colorBox.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);");
trace("parent", parent.width, parent.height, parent.x, parent.y);
trace("child", child.width, child.height, child.x, child.y);
```

If I add Sprite on Sprite, parent.width is 100, even if child.x = 20. The same about height and y.

But if I change the code like this:

```
var parent:Sprite = new Sprite();
var child:Sprite = new Sprite();

parent.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 0, 0); // the difference

addChild(parent);
parent.addChild(child);

child.x = 20;
child.y = 20;
child.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
child.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
trace("colorBox.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);");
trace("colorBox.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);");
trace("parent", parent.width, parent.height, parent.x, parent.y);
trace("child", child.width, child.height, child.x, child.y);
```

the parent width becomes equivalent to 120.

Why is it so? How can I get parent's width resized by child without "parent.graphics.drawRect" hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of a Sprite is not necessarily calculated from its origin (0, 0). It is calculated based on the bounds of the elements within it, starting at the content's left-most point. Since the child element's left-most point is 20, the width is calculated from there. When you add graphics to (0, 0) the width is calculated from the new left-most point (0, 0).

There are a couple ways to work with this:

Create your own width calculation method, that returns the width based on the child's offset and width:

```
function myWidth():Number {
    return child.x + child.width;
}
```

Do what you've already done, and add an invisible element to the parent's origin.

Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#width

Comment: Thank you, Craig! We couldn't cope with this issue for a whole day.